# Using Android features layer over multiple libraries integration

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'd like to ask if there is any point in using Android Features for multiple libraries integration or if there is a better way implementing this type of architecture.

**What do I mean by multiple libraries integration?**

Let's say I've got multiple projects regarding one application, that implement different libraries. For example, I've got an application for point of sale and this application is used over multiple devices with different vendors. Assuming there are three vendors and each one of those vendors have different SDKs, therefore I got to create three different projects of the same application that applies the three different SDKs. Right now, the architecture looks like the following:
[image]

The problem with this scheme is that all three of the applications share same logic, except the SDK implementations and once a change is made, I'd have to go through all three projects and make the changes there. That is what I want to avoid.

**How I imagine it?**

I imagine the project "My Application" as one project where it has a module or Android Feature (not sure which one is correct, where this whole question comes to) which module takes care of separating the three vendors' SDKs, for example. A schematic is available down below:
[image]

Summarizing the whole information, what would be the best approach to this problem and are Android Features sufficient enough to provide this type of functionality, or I interpret it wrong?

Comment: I think your bottom diagram is the obvious solution. You can use build flavors to select between your dependencies. In this case your project has five modules. One that defines the interface(s) for your abstract layer, three modules that wrap the sdks in the interface(s), and then your app. https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants